# What Prevents C++Builder "Method Toxicity Metrics..." from Listing Any Methods?

Tags: c++builder, metrics

I'm using C++Builder 11.1. I have a completed 32-bit app in Debug configuration and want to check the toxicity metrics. When I open Project > Method Toxicity Metrics..., the window opens with column headings but nothing is listed in the window. What might prevent the listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wanted to use this too, but apparently it isn't supported in C++ Builder. See [CB 11 documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Source_Code_Audits_and_Metrics)